# Creating contour plots without using numpy.meshgrid method?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to use the example given [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html) to produce contour plots of a function that I use. I have a problem using numpy.meshgrid with this function as it gives me `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`.
So I produced instead a list that is taking the value for the different points in the matrix in this fashion:

```
n_range = numpy.linspace(1,10,100)
mass_range = numpy.logspace(1,6,100)
mu = []
for n in n_range:
    for mass in mass_range:
        mu.append(function(n,mass))
n_range, mass_range = numpy.meshgrid(n_range, mass_range)
```

So now `mu` has entries that correspond to

```
mu[100*i + j] = function(n_range[i], mass_range[j])
```

How can I now organize another variable that will take the values from mu and will give the right form so I can plot this variable in respect to the `numpy.meshgrid` that I have created?

As first attempt I tried to use this function:

```
def plot_contour_mu():
    n_range = np.linspace(1,10,10)
    mass_range = np.logspace(1,6,10)
    n_range, mass_range = np.meshgrid(n_range, mass_range)
    mu = mu0_n_mDM(n_range, mass_range)
```

But this resulted in the above mentioned ValueError, that was pointing to where I calculate the value for mu0_n_nDM, specifically to the line :

```
File "mucalc.py", line 109, in mu_0_n_nDM
    return C * B * integrate.romberg(integrand,z_min,z_i)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py", line 653, in romberg
    ordsum = ordsum + _difftrap(vfunc, interval, n)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py", line 527, in _difftrap
    s = sum(function(points),0)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py", line 110, in vfunc
    output[0] = y0
```

Comment: Maybe post how you use `meshgrid`? It'll be easier to fix that than to write it anew ;)

Comment: I added now the piece of code I used in the previous attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to reshape the `mu` by `mu=np.array(mu).reshape(100,100)`, and plot it by `plt.contourf(n_range,mass_range,mu.T)`

```
mu=np.array(mu).reshape(100,100)
plt.contourf(n_range,mass_range,mu.T)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the tutorial for 3d plotting - 
http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html

And the docs for numpy meshgrid to see what type of object it returns - 
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html

Your n_range, mass_range are two dimensional numpy arrays.  Your mu must be the same.  This can be accomplished by passing n_range and mass_range as arguments to your function (assuming your function can operate on numpy arrays).

Comment: But what if my function cannot operate on numpy arrays? (it uses scipy.integrate.romberg method, and this gives an error when I try to give it as input an array)

Comment: Then you may need to reshape mu (see CT Zhu's answer).  Just keep in mind that looping through elements is generally much slower than operating on numpy datatypes with numpy/scipy methods.